# How to prevent my app from capturing screen recording in android?

Tags: android, screen, privacy

I am working on video player app and I want no other app can record my video and audio as well. I am using simple **VideoView** to run videos in my app.

I have tried this code, this code prevents from taking the screenshot only.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

## Problem

**But when I downloaded a screen recording app i.e. DU Recorder and check by recording, it's recording my video's screen and audio as well, this i don't want.**

Could anyone help me from this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do what you ask. Some application that I tested who not allow the screenshot cannot prevent the recording from external application like DU Recorder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using **SurefaceView** with media player then use SurfaceView.setSecure(true) , then your video will be secured from any other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Pull down your bar on the screen go to settings and find shortcut keys then you can turn off the automatic screenshot setting

Comment: We need through programmatically